# No overload expects 3 arguments, but overloads do exist that expect either 3 or Infinity arguments

Tags: typescript, overloading

[image]
The sample code can be seen [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHkDcFMCcBsD2BDAJgWAFADMCuA7AYwBcBLRfUABzVVPwHMAKZeeALlH1wFsAjOAEpOkRKVQBuLHiJkK1WvWbFEVAIL5UAIUTEVPTt35wANKHjRsxDagBKpBgAtih3gNjDQo8VJwES5JQ0qHSMTCrqmjp6iAZcbqbmltaa9k4u8cawZrqOcK5Znt6S0v5yQYphEQXuZrAOzjWJfLr6TdlJVu1FYiWYpbKBCiFKLO1mfAD846CE05m1oKjzRu6CoADeWKCzFADOiBYAdEjMyBNmhGaoglgAvlhYhPvEoMiwsKAAvKAA2gAMAF1HphgqFmEdIe8OgBGMwAJjMAGZBEA)

> No overload expects 3 arguments, but overloads do exist that expect either 3 or Infinity arguments.

Because the first argument may be empty after expansion, it says "No overload expects 3 arguments", but there is indeed a case where the method overload expects 3 arguments, which is very contradictory.

So why not just throw an error like this: `Expected 1-4 arguments, but got 3 or Infinity arguments. (2554)`

Of course, there are problems with its description, so is there a more appropriate description?